# Como unir Arrays generados por un Foreach

Tags: php, array, foreach

Hola que tal tengo este código y me encuentro con el problema que en mi caso me genera 3 arrays y yo quisiera tenerlo todo dentro de solo 1.

¿Como podría hacerlo?

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $object) {


$tipodes = $object->product_type;
$codigop =  $object->second_name;


$publicar =   array(

    "unidad_de_medida"          => $tipodes,
    "codigo"                    => $codigop,

);


echo $publicar;
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en cada iteracción del foreach estás declarando nuevamente el array `$publicar`. Necesitarás concatenar los arrays de alguna manera. Puedes utilizar la función `array_push()` de la siguiente manera.

```
$array_final = array();

foreach ($rows as $key => $object) {

    $tipodes = $object->product_type;
    $codigop =  $object->second_name;

    $publicar = array(

        "unidad_de_medida" => $tipodes,
        "codigo" => $codigop,
    );

    array_push($array_final, $publicar);
}

print_r($array_final);
```

Espero que sea de ayuda. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es declarar `$publicar` antes del foreach y tener el cuidado para adentro ir agregando los elementos cómo los necesitas. Con [array_push](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) por ejemplo.

Falta ver más tu código y poner ejemplos para que te podamos ayudar mejor. 
Puedes empezar poniendo: lo que tengo es estos objetos y quiero este resultado.

Answer (score 0):

También lo puedes hacer creando un array a cada paso del bucle y pasándolo metiéndolo dentro del array final:

```
<?php 
    $publicar=array();
    foreach ($rows as $key => $object) {
        $publicar[]= array (
                            'unidad_de_medida'=$object->product_type, 
                            'codigo'=$object->second_name
                           );
        }
    #Prueba
    var_dump($publicar);
?>
```

[Según el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) esta forma es más rápida, porque evita una llamada suplementaria a `array_push`:

> Nota: Si se utiliza `array_push()` para añadir un solo elemento al
>   array, es mejor utilizar `$array[]` = ya que de esta forma no existe
>   la sobrecarga de llamar a una función.

Usando este estilo no es obligatorio declarar el array antes. Pero es mejor declararlo, no cediendo así ante la *permisividad* de PHP.